# Implementation of image downscaling by local averaging too slow in python

Tags: python, image-processing, image-scaling

I have a python function which takes a three dimensional array representing an RGB image as input, and outputs another three dimensional array that represents the scaled down version of the original image. I use the concept of local averaging to calculate the pixel values of the scaled down matrix. Even though my implementation is linear in size of the input array, it still takes a whole lot of time for the function to finish, for slightly large images (eg. 1536 X 2048). Here's my code

```
import numpy as np
import math

def scale_down_image(image, height, width):
    '''
    Scales down a given image bitmap to new dimensions, provided that
    the new dimesions dont exceed those of the image to be 
    scaled
    '''

    # determine original image dimensions
    image_height = image.shape[0]
    image_width = image.shape[1]
    assert image_height >= height and image_width >= width

    # create row_arr and col_arr arrays which help in querying window sum
    image = np.array(image, dtype=np.uint64)
    row_arr = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint64)
    col_arr = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint64)
    for i in range(image.shape[2]):
        for j in range(image.shape[0]):
            for k in range(image.shape[1]):
                if j == 0 and k == 0:
                    row_arr[j][k][i] = image[j][k][i]
                    col_arr[j][k][i] = image[j][k][i]
                elif j == 0:
                    row_arr[j][k][i] = row_arr[j][k - 1][i] + image[j][k][i]
                    col_arr[j][k][i] = image[j][k][i]
                elif k == 0:
                    row_arr[j][k][i] = image[j][k][i]
                    col_arr[j][k][i] = col_arr[j - 1][k][i] + image[j][k][i]
                else:
                    row_arr[j][k][i] = row_arr[j][k - 1][i] + image[j][k][i]
                    col_arr[j][k][i] = col_arr[j - 1][k][i] + image[j][k][i]

    # create range_query_arr array, which helps in querying window sum 
    range_query_arr = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint64)
    for i in range(image.shape[2]):
        for j in range(image.shape[0]):
            for k in range(image.shape[1]):
                if j == 0 and k == 0:
                    range_query_arr[j][k][i] = image[j][k][i]
                elif j == 0:
                    range_query_arr[j][k][i] = row_arr[j][k][i]
                elif k == 0:
                    range_query_arr[j][k][i] = col_arr[j][k][i]
                else:
                    range_query_arr[j][k][i] = (range_query_arr[j - 1][k - 1][i] + 
                        row_arr[j][k - 1][i] + col_arr[j - 1][k][i] + image[j][k][i])

    # define a recursive function query, which computes the sum of elements in any window
    def query(y1, x1, y2, x2, channel):
        assert 0 <= channel < image.shape[2]
        if not (0 <= y1 < image.shape[0] and 0 <= x1 < image.shape[1] and 0 <= y2 < image.shape[0] 
                        and 0 <= x2 < image.shape[1] and y1 <= y2 and x1 <= x2):
            return 0
        else:
            return (range_query_arr[y2][x2][channel] - query(0, 0, y2, x1 - 1, channel) - 
                query(0, 0, y1 - 1, x2, channel) + query(0, 0, y1 - 1, x1 - 1, channel))

    # determine window dimensions
    window_height = int(math.ceil(image_height / height))
    window_width = int(math.ceil(image_width / width))

    # compute scaled image
    scaled_image = np.zeros((height, width, image.shape[2]), dtype=np.uint64)
    for i in range(scaled_image.shape[2]):
        for j in range(scaled_image.shape[0]):
            for k in range(scaled_image.shape[1]):
                y1 = max(0, int(((j + 1) / height) * image_height - 1 - window_height / 2))
                x1 = max(0, int(((k + 1) / width) * image_width - 1 - window_width / 2))
                y2 = min(image_height - 1, y1 + window_height - 1)
                x2 = min(image_width - 1, x1 + window_width - 1)
                scaled_image[j][k][i] = query(y1, x1, y2, x2, i) // ((y2 - y1 + 1) * 
                    (x2 - x1 + 1))

    # return scaled image
    return np.array(scaled_image, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Could you suggest something that would make this run faster? Should I use another algorithm? Will moving my code to C++ help?

Comment: Yes, implementing it in C++ would make it much faster. You could also use Numba to speed it up significantly. Or you could use one of the many Python packages that exist that already have this implemented in a compiled language. That last one has the added advantage that you'll have less code to maintain and you'll likely have a faster implementation than what you could write yourself in C++.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# blah blah your code here
small_image = cv2.resize(image, (width, height), cv2.INTER_AREA)
# blah blah enjoy small image
```

More examples [here](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) (among other places)